# EVReflection with NSManagedObject Crashes / not Working

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, reflection, nsmanagedobject

hI: I've been using EVReflection to make our Network Layer Fully Restful and I Must say: AWESOME WORK! Thanks to @evermeer for this Library. you can get it here: https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection

Now, to the Issue:

The Next Step is to get those Objects Straight into CORE DATA. Here is one of the Classes in Question

// Here is the Object With the EVReflectable Extension as the Documentation Claims:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import EVReflection

public class NGTripSummary: NSManagedObject { }

extension NGTripSummary: EVReflectable { }
```

// and HERE are the Object Properties:

// NGTripSummary+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension NGTripSummary {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NGTripSummary> {
        return NSFetchRequest<NGTripSummary>(entityName: "NGTripSummary")
    }

    @NSManaged public var carId: Int64
    @NSManaged public var citiesVisited: NSObject?
    @NSManaged public var cost: Double
    @NSManaged public var distance: Double
    @NSManaged public var globalStartDate: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var globalEndDate: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var kpl: Double
    @NSManaged public var litres: Double
    @NSManaged public var routeLocations: NSObject?
    @NSManaged public var sessionId: Int64
    @NSManaged public var localStartDate: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var localEndDate: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var duration: Int64
    @NSManaged public var speed: Double
    @NSManaged public var _id: Int64
    @NSManaged public var sessionUuid: String?
    @NSManaged public var tripUuid: String?

}
```

// . here is the JSON String that Represents a Demo Object:

```
let tripData = "{\"id\":26105240,\"userId\":25796277,\"carId\":25817551,\"vehicleId\":57812351,\"sessionUuid\":\"53324259-aa69-41c8-8f9e-c62bdb70f165\",\"tripUuid\":\"afdd8f55-6d14-4cf9-bd9f-5b6da47aaf93\",\"localStartDate\":1487170622490,\"localEndDate\":1487178323654,\"globalStartDate\":1487163422490,\"globalEndDate\":1487171123654,\"routeLocations\":null,\"litres\":24.7699,\"kpl\":0.0772,\"cost\":153.3258,\"distance\":1.9132,\"duration\":491.958,\"speed\":14.0}"
```

// and HERE is the Method I'm Trying to use to Create this Mock Object:

```
func makeMockData() {
    let singleTrip = NGTripSummary(json: tripData)
    print("Single Trip: \(singleTrip)")
}
```

// NOW: When Creating the Object, the Crash Happens HERE @ class EVReflection:

```
        // Call your own object validators that comply to the format: validate<Key>:Error:
            do {
                var setValue: AnyObject? = value as AnyObject?
/* LINE 923: CRASH HAPPENS HERE -> */  try anyObject.validateValue(&setValue, forKey: key)
                anyObject.setValue(setValue, forKey: key)
            } catch _ {
                (anyObject as? EVReflectable)?.addStatusMessage(.InvalidValue, message: "Not a valid value for object `\(NSStringFromClass(type(of: (anyObject as AnyObject))))`, type `\(type)`, key  `\(key)`, value `\(value)`")
                print("INFO: Not a valid value for object `\(NSStringFromClass(type(of: (anyObject as AnyObject))))`, type `\(type)`, key  `\(key)`, value `\(value)`")
            }
```

////////////////// REASON FOR CRASH ////////////////////

[error] error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'NGTripSummary'
CoreData: error: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'NGTripSummary'

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

-> Anybody, PLEASE HELP :-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EVReflection now has a Cocoapods subspec for CoreData. For more information see https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection/tree/master/Source/CoreData

It will let you write code like this:\

```
let moc: NSManagedObjectContext = EVReflectionTestsData().moc // Your code for getting the NSManagedObjectContext.

let obj = CoreDataPerson(context: moc, json: "{\"firstName\" : \"Edwin\", \"lastName\" : \"Vermeer\"}")

try! moc.save() //TODO: implement error handling
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message describes the exact problem. You appear to be creating instances of `NGTripSummary` with this line of code:

```
let singleTrip = NGTripSummary(json: tripData)
```

But `NGTripSummary` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`, and you're never calling the designated initializer for `NSManagedObject`. That's required. You must call `init(entity:insertInto:)` on `NSManagedObject`, or else use the factory method `insertNewObject(forEntityName:into:)` on `NSEntityDescription` to get a valid managed object. If you don't, you get this specific error and your app crashes.

If you need to create instances using `tripData`, you can do that, but you also need to provide a managed object context and an entity description. You could do that with a convenience initializer on your class, which would call the designated initializer as part of the initialization process.

Comment: Hi @Tom Harrington, could you please provide an Example of a designated Initializer?./ Thanks

Comment: @HernanArber every class has a designated initializer, and for `NSManagedObject` it's the one I mentioned in my answer. If you're not sure what a designated initializer is, take a look at Apple's [documentation on class initialization in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203).